# Creating an array from text file for a maze

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python, and iI am making a maze solver in python.
This is the maze from a text file. and I want to read it with sys.argv
but I don't know how to convert the file to an array and print it, to be able to use it after. Start is at (0,1) and exit at bottom right.

```
# ###
# # #
#   #
# # #
### #
```

I tried split and append but it only showed the first line.
And I can print the maze whith this line of code

```
 with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as maze:
      print(maze.read())
```

But it's not really usefull i think.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as maze:
    m = maze.read()
    print([list(line) for line in m.split('\n')])
```

This splits the maze into a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it as well with this

```
with open('sys.argv', 'r') as maze:
      print(maze.read())
```